# Python: Get datetime (with timezone info) from number (epoch time) and convert it to string of specific date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

While scraping data from the internet, I am getting a number as a response instead of the date-time string. Below are few example:

```
1508486400   --  instead of "2017, 20 Oct 10:00:00"
1510974000   --  instead of "2017, 18 Nov 4:00:00"
1388664000   --  instead of "2014, 02 Jan 13:00:00"
```

I want to convert these number to the corresponding date in the format `"dd/mm/yyyy"`. Though preserving the timezone is not a mandate, but it is good if I could get the string based on the timezone to which my dates belong.

The dates I am trying to extract from the number belongs to `"CAT+2:00:00"` timezone.

Comment: It's a [timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp)... `datetime.fromtimestamp(1508486400)` -> `datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 20, 9, 0)`

Comment: @BhargavRao I think this could be a good question as I am not able to find any question on SO which converts epochtime to `datetime` with the time-zone info. Though the question requires some editting

Comment: Sure, @Moinuddin, do edit the post and make it better! Remember that if a question is duplicate, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's a bad post. It will (and should) remain as a signpost pointing towards the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time that you are having is the [**UNIX time**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (also known as Epoch or POSIX time). You can convert it into the [**`datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object and then format it as:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> my_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(1508486400)
>>> my_datetime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'20/10/2017'
```

**Edit**: Based on desired time you mentioned, looks like you expect the time to be in "CAT+2:00:00" timezone. In order to do that, you may use [**`pytz`**](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) module with timezone "Africa/Harare" as:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz

>>> my_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(1508486400, tz= pytz.timezone('Africa/Harare'))
# Will hold the date time object as:
# datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 20, 10, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Africa/Harare' CAT+2:00:00 STD>)

>>> my_datetime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'20/10/2017'
```

You can get the list of all timezones using **`pytz.all_timezones`**.

Also take a look at [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) wiki.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using time() function it is number of ticks since 12:00am, January 1, 1970.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `utcfromtimestamp()` from `datetime` to convert `timestamp` to `yyyy/mm/dd` format:

```
import datetime

t = "1508486400"
print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(t)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

if you want to have the time as well, use `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` in `strftime` method. this [link](http://strftime.org/) will help you to get your desired format from `strftime`